# Why is CloudFormation using a strange role to execute updates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, roles, aws-roles

I was trying to update a stack to add a policy to a role. The role I used to push the stack updates had [`AdministratorAccess`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_job-functions.html#jf_administrator), so I expected the updates to not run into permission problems. However, I got a strange error message:

> API: `iam:PutRolePolicy` User: `arn:aws:sts::xxxxx:assumed-role/NotAdmin/yyyy` is not authorized to perform: `iam:PutRolePolicy` on resource: role `zzzz` because no identity-based policy allows the `iam:PutRolePolicy` action

The ARN of the role in the error message is a different user from the one I used to push the updates. It was a role with limited permissions that a script uses to periodically update that stack.

I tried using an explicit `--role-arn` argument:

```
aws cloudformation update-stack --region xxx --stack-name xxx --role-arn arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/RoleWithAdminAccess
```

but then I received this error message:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the UpdateStack operation: Role arn:aws:iam::xxx:role/RoleWithAdminAccess is invalid or cannot be assumed

How can I get this stack update to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is happening because `--role-arn` is "sticky"

From `https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudformation/update-stack.html`

> If you don't specify a value, CloudFormation uses the role that was previously associated with the stack. If no role is available, CloudFormation uses a temporary session that is generated from your user credentials.

Before `--role-arn` was being specified, CFN was indeed using a session based on the user credentials and had all permissions. However, after the first update where `--role-arn NotAdmin` was specified, CFN now remembers that role as the "stack role." Subsequent updates that don't specify `--role-arn` default to using that role, hence the permission problems.

As to why `RoleWithAdminAccess` cannot be assumed -- that's because using the role via `--role-arn` as opposed to the default session inheritance requires an explicit grant to `Principal: {Service: "cloudformation.amazonaws.com"}` that allows assuming the role